# How do I correspond lists so that they sort in the same pattern?

Tags: python, list

So I am trying to create a program (In Python) that will give the win/loss percentage of teams. There are four teams in a list, for example `team_list = [team0, team1, team2, team3]`.

What I want to do is create a second list that contains the Win/Loss percentage `w_l_pct = [team1pct, etc.]`.

What I want to do is sort the `list`s so that the highest percentage in `w_l_pct` is first in the list, and that `team_list` is sorted in the exact same way, so that the program can do `print(f"{team_list[0]} had the highest Win/Loss percentage with {w_l_pct[0]}% of their games being wins!")` without it being mixed up. I am still new to this so if it could be explained with simpler methods that would be great, thank you guys.

Comment: The pattern you are describing is called Parallel arrays: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array

Comment: It sounds like you just need a single `list` of `dict` or similar.

Comment: The easier way to do this is to make it one list, maybe with a tuple of `(team, pct)`.  Now you can sort it at will, and everything stays together,  If there are multiple fields, use a class or a `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two arrays:

```py
team_list = ["team0", "team1", "team2", "team3"]
team_list_per = [0.43, 0.23, 0.76, 0.1]
```

after sorting the `team_list_per` we need the sorted indices:

```py
team_list_per_tup = [(per,ind) for ind, per in enumerate(team_list_per)]
```

so we can sort `team_list_per_tup` to keep the original indices:

```py
team_list_per_tup.sort()
team_list_per_tup = team_list_per_tup[::-1]

team_list_sorted = [i for i in range(len(team_list))]
team_list_per_sorted = [i for i in range(len(team_list))]
for i, item in enumerate(team_list_per_tup):
    team_list_sorted[i] = team_list[item[1]]
    team_list_per_sorted[i] = team_list_per[item[1]]
```

and

```py
print(f"highest chance {team_list_sorted[0]}:{team_list_per_sorted[0]}")
```